# Pyserial  version 2.6 not working after install on python3

Tags: python, pyserial

This is the error that I get after typing import serial. I'm running osx snow leopard, python3.2 and there were no errors when I installed pyserial.

```
       import serial
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "serial/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from serial.serialposix import *
    File "serial/serialposix.py", line 64
    50:      0000001,
               ^
```

Comment: What version of pyserial did you download?

Comment: How did you install it? That version works for me installed with `pip install pyserial`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0000001` is an invalid token in Python 3, because it used to be parsed as an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal in Python 2, and that behavior was dropped in favor of the `0o` prefix.

`0o0000001` would work (as would `0o1`, or simply `1`).

I don't exactly know why your version of pySerial contains such a literal, but it will not work on Python 3 as it is. Try upgrading, as Martijn suggests.

Comment: I downloaded what I thought was the most recent version from pyserial.

Comment: is there another version beyond 2.6?

Comment: So i'm still in the same boat. I've re-installed several times. The outcome is still the same. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: @user, the [current version of `serialposix.py`](http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyserial/trunk/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py?revision=452&view=markup) exposes this bug (see `baudrate_constants` from line 62 onwards). I don't think the module owner intended to break Python 3 compatibility, so this is probably a bug... *Or not, Martijn apparently nailed it :)*

Comment: Do you think it's possible to edit serialposix.py and correct the problem?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Nope, setup.py uses 2to3 to convert to python 3 code.

Comment: I'm still a beginner. How would I verify that?

Comment: @user1124541: See my answer, I've linked to various options you have to install the library properly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to [install pyserial with the included `setup.py` script](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html), or better still, use [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) or [`distribute`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) to install the package for you.

The pyserial code base is written for python 2 but the [2to3 code translator](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) will be run on the code base when installing with python 3.

Comment: in the package directory I typed sudo python3 setup.py install

Comment: @user1124541: And that worked, or not? Is the original package directory also on your python path? If so, it would interfere.

Comment: That's the only command I've used so far to install the package. I never saw any errors when installing it, but when invoking import serial I could not get it to work. That was my other question. Is there a specific place where i should be installing this?

Comment: @user1124541: read the included links; `python3.2 setup.py install` will install it for your whole python3.2 installation in a central location, where it *normally* would be imported from.

Comment: I think there is something else going on. The 2/3 conversion doesn't seem to be happening correctly. I have tried everything that has been posted and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Again: I strongly suspect that python is loading the downloaded package *first*, thus getting the wrong code. What does `import sys; print sys.modules['serial']` tell you (after importing serial)?

Comment: I receive an error after typing that. I don't think it's python3.2 syntax. But when I typed print (sys.modules) i didn't see pyserial listed.

Comment: Also. I just tried using the defacto python distro. And serial works fine with it, so somehow there was confusion.